# Ubuntu 18.10 Meld missing preferences option

Tags: 18.10, meld

The merge/diff tool Meld is missing preferences option (Edit -> preferences) on Ubuntu 18.10. Is this an general issue or specific to my Ubuntu installation? How can it fixed?

Update for anyone facing the same issue: 
Seems like a Gnome-Shell feature.
Click on the small Down Arrow next to the "Meld" icon on the shell menu bar.

Comment: Small note: on other fully-functional traditional desktops such as KDE,  MATE and Xfce the Preferences option [is placed in the first menu item named Meld](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkHHO.png).

Comment: goddamnit, I face this problem for decades! Now again, it's missing and I can't find it.
Meld developers are u kidding us??

Answer (score 15):

The preferences menu has moved to the top bar just next to the `Activities` badge. This is not only true for `meld` but also for many other GNOME applications, e.g. `gedit`.

[image]

I don't know why they did it and consider it totally useless and counter intuitive, but that's how it works.

Comment: I have a dual-screen setup and this menu was on the other screen from the app. No wonder I couldn't find it !

Comment: so unintuitive would have never found it

Answer (score 9):

1. `sudo vim /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/meld/meldwindow.py` (or, instead of `vim`, use any other text editor)
2. replace
   `if not gtk_settings.props.gtk_shell_shows_app_menu:`
   to
   `if gtk_settings.props.gtk_shell_shows_app_menu:`
3. **Profit!**

Works on `Ubuntu 19.04`

Comment: This is the only way I got it to work!

Comment: Works on 18.04, Meld 3.18.0.

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 21.10, Meld 3.20.4

Answer (score 3):

I fixed it by installing `gnome-tweaks` and disabling "app menu" under "top bar".